# Better practice than returning a bunch of Nones when function runs into an issue?

Tags: python, function

I often have functions that return multiple outputs which are structured like so:

```
def f(vars):
    ...
    if something_unexpected():
        return None, None
    ...
    # normal return 

    return value1, value2
```

In this case, there might be a infrequent problem that `something_unexpected` detects (say, a empty dataframe when the routine expects at least one row of data), and so I want to return a value to the caller that says to ignore the output and skip over it. If this were a single return function then returning `None` once would seem fine, but when I'm returning multiple values it seems sloppy to return multiple copies of None just so the caller has the right number of arguments to unpack.

What are some better ways of coding up this construct? Is simply having the caller use a try-except block and the function raising an exception the way to go, or is there another example of good practice to use here?

Edit: Of course I could return the pair of outputs into a single variable, but then I'd have to call the function like

```
results = f(inputs)
if results is None:
    continue
varname1, varname2 = results[0], results[1]
```

rather than the more clean-seeming

```
varname1, varname2 = f(inputs)
if varname1 is None:
    continue
```

Comment: Generally, raising on an exception is a pretty normal way to handle this. I don't really see anything grievously wrong with `return None, None`, though... Note, you never really return multiple values, in this case, you are always returning a *single value*, a tuple object

Comment: If your code encounters an *exceptional* condition – ``raise`` an Exception.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you are correct. Thanks for the correction. I edited the question to omit that error.

Comment: Also note, `varname1, varname2 = results[0], results[1]` could just be `varname1, varname2 = results`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on where you want to handle this behavior, but exceptions are a pretty standard way to do this. Without exceptions, you could still return `None, None`:

```py
a, b = f(inputs)

if None in (a, b):
    print("Got something bad!")
    continue
```

Though, I think it might be better to `raise` in your function and catch it instead:

```py
def f():
    if unexpected:
        raise ValueError("Got empty values")
    else:
        return val1, val2

try:
    a, b = f()
except ValueError:
    print("bad behavior in f, skipping")
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to raise an exception:

```
if something_unexpected():
   raise ValueError("Something unexpected happened")
```

**REFERENCES:**

> Explicit is better than implicit.
> Errors should never pass silently.
> Unless explicitly silenced.

*[PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)*